# Gimp gdk_pixbuf_save fails with AccessViolationException but I don't know why?

Tags: .net, 64-bit, pdf-generation, access-violation, gimp

I'm using code I found to rasterize SVG files into image files. The link is http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_24547525.html. My code looks identical but I'm getting an access violation of:

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."`

In order to eliminate the obvious: I use an svg file from the Gimp directory so I have a known good file. I use e: as the save to file location so that the library doesn't hit any security/permission stuff. I'm running Visual Studio with Admin privileges in case that is an issue. My box is 64 bit and I have the Local.testsettings set to "Run test in 64 pit process on 64 bit machine."

Any ideas?

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TA.Rasterizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes SVG image file type and converts to PNG image file type. 
    /// Gimp must be installed. Gimp dll location must be in the web.config
    /// file key "ThreatAnalyzer-DllDirectoryForGimp".
    /// <summary>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
    /// http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_24547525.html
    /// </summary>    /// </summary>
    public static class Rasterizer
    {
        // C:\Windows\System32
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string pathname);

        [DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void g_type_init();

        [DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size(string file_name, int width, int height, out IntPtr error);

        [DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool gdk_pixbuf_save(IntPtr pixbuf, string filename, string type, out IntPtr error, __arglist);
        //static extern bool gdk_pixbuf_save_to_buffer(

        /// <summary>
        /// Get location of Gimp installed Dlls from web.config appsettings key/value.
        /// Key name is found in this.webConfigFileAppSettingsGimp
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string GetGimpDllLocationFromConfigurationFile(bool webapp, string nonDefaultConfigFileName)
        {
            // connect to config file
            Configuration rasterizerConfiguration = new TA.Rasterizer.Configuration(webapp, nonDefaultConfigFileName);

            // grab config setting
            return rasterizerConfiguration.Get("ThreatAnalyzer-DllDirectoryForGimp");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
        /// You must check that file exists after call in order to check success. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputFileName">SVG file to be converted</param>
        /// <param name="outputFileName">PNG file as final product</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static void SvgToPng(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, bool webapp, string nonDefaultConfigFileName)
        {
            string gimpDllLocation = GetGimpDllLocationFromConfigurationFile(webapp, nonDefaultConfigFileName);

            bool rasterizeSuccess = ExternRaster.RasterizeSvg(inputFileName, outputFileName, gimpDllLocation);

            if (!rasterizeSuccess)
            {
                Int32 err = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(err);
            }
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
    /// http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_24547525.html
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class ExternRaster
    {

        public static bool RasterizeSvg(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, string gimpDllLocation)
        {
            bool callSuccessful = SetDllDirectory(gimpDllLocation);
            if (!callSuccessful)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not set DLL directory");
            }
            g_type_init();
            IntPtr error1;
            IntPtr result = rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size(@"E:\green.svg", -1, -1, out error1);
            if (error1 != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception(Marshal.ReadInt32(error1).ToString());
            }

            IntPtr error2;
            callSuccessful = gdk_pixbuf_save(result, @"E:\green.jpg", "jpg", out error2, __arglist(null));
            if (!callSuccessful)
            {
                throw new Exception(error2.ToInt32().ToString());
            }

            return true;
        }

    }



    }
}
```

I'm access the code from an MSTest unit test:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for RasterizeSvg
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void RasterizeSvgTest()
    {
        // arrange
        string svgFileNameInAppDirectory = "1kijvsrewxxr3mdvlwitjvyu-pie.svg";

        string currentClassLibDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Replace(@"\bin\debug\","");
        string pathToAppData = Setup.GetDataPath(); 
        string inputFileName = Path.Combine(pathToAppData, svgFileNameInAppDirectory);
        string outputFileName = Path.Combine(pathToAppData, svgFileNameInAppDirectory.Replace("svg","png"));
        bool webapp = false; 
        string nonDefaultConfigFileName = string.Empty; 

        // act
        Rasterizer.SvgToPng(inputFileName, outputFileName, webapp, nonDefaultConfigFileName);

        // assert
        bool fileExists = File.Exists(outputFileName);
        Assert.IsTrue(fileExists);

        // cleanup
        if (fileExists)
        {
            File.Delete(outputFileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you modify your import with "MarshallAs" as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182206(v=vs.80).aspx? 

Also, this might be a non-issue, but it looks from the documentation (here: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-file-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save) that the default file types to save are  "jpeg", "png" and "ico". You are saving as "jpg" (no "e").

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size`](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/2.36/rsvg-Using-RSVG-with-GdkPixbuf.html#rsvg-pixbuf-from-file-at-size) says that

> If an error occurred, error is set and NULL is returned.

To me this can mean that, when successful, your `error1` variable does not get set to a valid pointer. You should test the return value `result` instead.

I think what @GojiraDemonstah said about "jpg" versus "jpeg" is also important.

Additionally, `rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size` allocates a new `GdkPixbuf` and you don't have any code to free it. To do this you should also have

```
[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void g_object_unref(IntPtr obj);
```

in your imports and

```
g_object_unref(result);
```

after calling `gdk_pixbuf_save` to avoid leaking memory.